# C# Session doesn't increment on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a

`<asp:label ... >`

That I want to hide AFTER the user has visited 3 pages on our website. So I used page_load on the master.cs page to create a session

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            createSession();
            pageCounter.Text = Session["PagesViewed"].ToString();
            return;
        }
        Session["PagesViewed"] = ((int)Session["PagesViewed"] + 1);
        pageCounter.Text = Session["PagesViewed"].ToString();
    }
    protected void createSession()
    {
        Session["PagesViewed"] = 0;
    }
```

This code compiles and to test it out, I set a label to be the counter so I could see it working. Problem is, it comes out to 0 every time. It doesn't increment. I am not sure where my error is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function CreateSession is resetting the value to 0 every time the page loads for the first time.

This should probably be in you session start.

Or check to see if it exists before setting it:

```
protected void createSession()
{
    if(Session["PagesViewed"] == null)
    {
        Session["PagesViewed"] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove that `return;` in `if (!IsPostBack){}`

Your code will increment the session value in each page load. I' am not sure about the exact requirement anyway a better option to do this is:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    createSession();
else
{   
    Session["PagesViewed"] = (int)Session["PagesViewed"]+ 1;
}
pageCounter.Text = Session["PagesViewed"].ToString();
```

And there is another change you have to do is that create the session only if it is not yet created, So the `createSession()` method signature will be changed as:

```
 protected void createSession()
    {
       if (Session["PagesViewed"] == null) { Session["PagesViewed"] = 0;};
    }
```

Comment: removing the `return;` puts the counter stuck at 1 instead of 0.